# Read sms and open an application android studio

Tags: android

I plan to read the content of an sms and open an application base on the message in the sms. What method should I use? The application that I programmed may not be opened at that time, but still it must be able to read sms and open another application.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the [Telephony Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#SMS_DELIVER_ACTION) and register a receiver on the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.

Your app will need the READ_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS permissions.

There is a good in-depth howto [here](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android)

Comment: Will it work when the Application is removed form foreground?

Comment: Yes, just make sure to register your Receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml with the aforementioned Action.
The Android system will create an instance of the Receiver and call the onReceive() method of it

Comment: Thanks.. I have used this Telephony receiver.. That was long ago.. I wasn't knowing that it will work ..Even if the App is removed from Foreground

Comment: A little bit too deep for beginner like me haha

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
public class SmsListener extends 
BroadcastReceiver{



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
//                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: In your manifest file add the BroadcastReceiver-

```
<receiver android:name=".listener.SmsListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```